# validity of problem : Let $(X, T)$ be a Hausdorff space and let $T \subset T^*$. Show that $(X, T^*)$ is a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove following problem.

> Let $(X, T)$ be a Hausdorff space and let $T \subset T^*$. Show that $(X, T^*)$ is a Hausdorff space.

What I know is Hausdorff space is hereditary, i.e., subspace of Hausdorff is again Hausdorff.

Is above problem is correct?  If so How one can prove this?  It seems to me enlarging open sets can induce following :  For two distinct point $x\neq y$, we might contain open sets with overlap i.e., $O_x \cap O_y \neq \phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is quite trivial. Since $(X,T)$ is Hausdorff then any two points can be separated by open subsets from $T$. But $T\subseteq T^*$, hence those two open (in $T$) subsets are also open in $T^*$ which completes the proof.

> It seems to me enlarging open sets

We are not enlarging open sets here. We add new open sets to the old collection.

You seem to think about the operation as some kind of inverse to subspace topology. But that's not the case.